# Roblox, Lua: I want to save GUI text written by a local player into a datastore, but I can't

Tags: lua, roblox, datastore

The problem is the code can't get the text because it's a server-side script. I can't change it to local because then the datastore will stop working.

```
local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")

local ClassDataStore = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("ClassDataStore")

CreateClass.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    
    local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")

    local ClassDataStore = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("ClassDataStore")
    
    
    local classYear = tonumber(ClassYearTextBox.Text)
    local classLetter = ClassLetterTextBox.Text
    local teacherName = TeacherNameTextBox.Text
    local studentList = StudentList.Text
    local daySchedule = CreateDaySheduleText.Text
    local classKey = classYear .. "-" .. classLetter

    local success, errorText = pcall(function()
        local classData = {
            ClassNumber = classKey,
            TeacherName = teacherName,
            StudentList = studentList,
            DaySchedule = daySchedule
        }

        ClassDataStore:SetAsync(classKey, classData)
    end)
    if success then
        print("success")
    else
        print("error:", errorText)
    end end)
```

At first, when I realized that DataStore and LocalScript were incompatible, I moved Datastore to Server Script. Then I discovered a new problem - the server script can't read text that is written, for example, in a TextBox by a local player. I told ChatGPT about this problem and it said to use ReplicatedStorage for server and local code.

Server code part:

```
local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local ClassDataStore = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("ClassDataStore")

local function onSaveClassData(player, classYear, classLetter, teacherName, studentList, daySchedule)
    
    local classKey = classYear .. "-" .. classLetter

   
    local success, errorText = pcall(function()
        
        local classData = {
            ClassNumber = classKey,
            TeacherName = teacherName,
            StudentList = studentList,
            DaySchedule = daySchedule
        }

        
        ClassDataStore:SetAsync(classKey, classData)
    end)

    
    return success, errorText
end

local classDataEvent = Instance.new("RemoteEvent")
classDataEvent.Name = "ClassDataEvent"
classDataEvent.Parent = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
classDataEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(onSaveClassData)
```

Local code part:

```
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local classDataEvent = ReplicatedStorage.ClassDataEvent


CreateClass.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    local classYear = tonumber(ClassYearTextBox.Text)
    local classLetter = ClassLetterTextBox.Text
    local teacherName = TeacherNameTextBox.Text
    local studentList = StudentList.Text
    local daySchedule = CreateDaySheduleText.Text

    if classLetter == "" then
        print("'Class letter' can't be empty.")
        return
    end

    local success, errorText = classDataEvent:InvokeServer(classYear, classLetter, teacherName, studentList, daySchedule)

    if success then
        print("Success!")
    else
        print("Error:", errorText)
    end
end)
```

Yet, this still doesn't work. I also don't know anything about ReplicatedStorage functionality so I couldn't modify it somehow, so I am asking for help here, and please correct me if I am wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

A [remote event](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/RemoteEvent) does not have `:InvokeServer`, though it does have `:FireServer`.

You're going to want to do something like this in the serverside script (I would recommend putting it in ServerScriptService):

```lua
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local classDataEvent = Instance.new("RemoteEvent")
classDataEvent.Name = "classDataEvent"
classDataEvent.Parent = ReplicatedStorage

function onClassDataEvent(player, classYear, classLetter, teacherName, studentList, daySchedule) {
  # do stuff here
}

classDataEvent.OnServer:Connect(onClassDataEvent)
```

And client code like this:

```lua
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local classDataEvent = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("classDataEvent")

# Use this wherever you need it
classDataEvent:FireServer(classYear, classLetter, teacherName, studentList, daySchedule)
```

You had the right concept, just were using an incorrect function. Always make sure to check for errors in your output log too.